# Forms and Routes for Has Many Through Relation in Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a Rails newbie and trying to create a simple Rails4 application. I have User model which is generated by Devise GEM, Examination model and Participation models are both generated by scaffold generator.

These are my models:

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examination
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :examinations, :through => :participations
end
```

**And Database Structure:**

```
  create_table "participations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "examination_id"
    t.string   "exam_language_preference"
    ....
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "first_name"
    ....
  end

  create_table "examinations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "shortname"
    t.datetime "exam_date"
  end
```

Now, I would like to create the structure to make Users to be able to register to exams. In the index page of Examinations (app/views/examinations/index.html.erb) I want to add a "Register" button just next to default Show, Edit and Destroy buttons for each exam. When user click to "Register" button I want them to see a page where they can choose their exam language preference and submit their registrations.

Also I want a User can only 1 time register for an exam. I mean they can register for many exams but only 1 time for each.

I read the whole Rails Guide but couldn't find the right answer.

How can I do this kind of application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're not going to find the answer for your specific question in rails guides. :)

I'd suggest that you read more on:

- Validate uniqueness of an attribute using the scope option
- Nested resources

Comment: Thanks H-man. It's good to see you show me the path for my question.